# Insert statement crashes because of trigger

Tags: c#, sql

The error I get is this "The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK_vacation_users". The conflict occurred in database "TestAtt", table "dbo.users", column 'userID'."

I'm trying to insert into users with this:

```
INSERT into users (firstName, lastName, userName, password, team, fingerID, type, isActive) VALUES ('{0}', '{1}', '{2}', '{3}', '{4}', '{5}', '{6}', '{7}')",
firstNameAddBox.Text, lastNameAddBox.Text, userNameAddBox.Text, passwordAddBox.Text,
teamAddUserCombo.Text, fingerIdAddBox.Text, userTypeAddCombo.SelectedValue, isActiveCheck.Checked);
```

My users table looks like this:

```
CREATE TABLE
    users
    (
        userID INT NOT NULL IDENTITY,
        userName NVARCHAR(50) COLLATE Romanian_CI_AS NOT NULL,
        password NVARCHAR(100) COLLATE Romanian_CI_AS NOT NULL,
        firstName NVARCHAR(50) COLLATE Romanian_CI_AS NOT NULL,
        lastName NVARCHAR(50) COLLATE Romanian_CI_AS NOT NULL,
        team TINYINT NOT NULL,
        type TINYINT NOT NULL,
        fingerID SMALLINT NOT NULL,
        isActive BIT DEFAULT 1 NOT NULL,
        CONSTRAINT PK_users PRIMARY KEY (userID),
        CONSTRAINT FK_users_userType FOREIGN KEY (type) REFERENCES userType (typeID),
        CONSTRAINT users_idx UNIQUE (fingerID)
    );
```

The vacation table looks like this:

```
CREATE TABLE
    vacation
    (
        ID INT NOT NULL IDENTITY,
        userID INT NOT NULL,
        vacation TINYINT DEFAULT 0 NOT NULL,
        extraDays TINYINT DEFAULT 0 NOT NULL,
        PRIMARY KEY (ID),
        CONSTRAINT FK_vacation_users FOREIGN KEY (ID) REFERENCES users (userID)
    );
```

And this is the trigger:

```
ALTER TRIGGER "dbo"."newUserTrigger"
  on "dbo"."users"
  AFTER INSERT
  as 
begin
DECLARE @newUserID int
SELECT @newUserID = (SELECT userID FROM Inserted)
INSERT INTO vacation (userID) VALUES (@newUserID)
end;
```

So if I disable the trigger the insert works but with the trigger on it seems it wont insert the userID in the vacation table also.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think your foreign key is incorrect, the column that's referencing `users` is `userID`, not `ID`:

```
 CONSTRAINT FK_vacation_users FOREIGN KEY (userID) REFERENCES users (userID)
```

But your trigger is *also* broken because [`inserted`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191300.aspx) can contain *multiple* (or *no*) rows. So it should be:

```
ALTER TRIGGER "dbo"."newUserTrigger"
  on "dbo"."users"
  AFTER INSERT
  as 
begin
INSERT INTO vacation (userID) SELECT userID from Inserted
end;
```

Comment: Better answer than mine :)

Comment: @simonatrcl - well, we both identified "the" issue that was causing their problem. But I just included a bonus one that would (probably) come up and bite them sooner or later.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response! That did the job ;)

Answer (score 0):

Here's the problem:

```
CONSTRAINT FK_vacation_users FOREIGN KEY (ID) REFERENCES users (userID)
```

This is saying that the ID column in vacation must have a matching value in userId in users. I think (ID) should be (userID). It should work OK then.

Answer (score 0):

```
CONSTRAINT FK_vacation_users FOREIGN KEY (ID) REFERENCES users (userID)
```

should be

```
CONSTRAINT FK_vacation_users FOREIGN KEY (userID) REFERENCES users (ID)
```